# Debugging SSHD not responding on a wireless network to forwarded requests

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh

I am struggling to figure out why sshd is not responding to incoming requests. I have an ubuntu 18.04 system that is connected via wireless to a Linksys router.

```
Router:  10.132.2.1
Computer: 10.132.2.20  This is a static IP address on wlp1s0
```

sshd is listening on port 20 (reasons for odd port choice are not important).

I run /usr/sbin/sshd -dddD on the computer and see:

```
debug1: Bind to port 20 on 10.132.2.20
Server listening on 10.132.2.20 port 20
```

I try to connected to ssh from the WAN on a separate computer with ssh -vv -p 20 and see:

```
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to  [  ] port 20.
```

In a separate window on the computer 10.132.2.20, I run tcpdump -i wlp1s0 port 20 -n -Q inout and see:

```
10:05:29.787051 IP 107.77.240.93.40190 > 10.132.2.20.20: Flags [s], seq 1030904803, win 64240, options [mss 1390,sackOK,TS val 1967897638 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

There is no output from sshd.

EDIT:

As part of debugging this, I tried wiring the computer into the router that serves the WIFI.  This WORKS.  I was able to ssh in from the WAN to the IP address associated with the wireless connection.  Switching the wired connection back to the 10.132.1 network again caused the 10.132.2 ssh connection to fail.  So the problem is something having to do with ssh living on two disparate networks.  I tried making a copy of the sshd service so that I had one that was serving the 10.132.1.* network and another one that was serving the 10.132.2.* network.  This again fails, but again, only when the computer is on two networks.  If the wired network and wireless network are on the same router, then it works.

EDIT 2:

Here is the output from ip route (I'm not sure how to decode everything that is here -- In my basic understanding, it looks like there are two networks, with 10.132.1.1 prioritized (metric 100) over 10.132.2.1)

```
default via 10.132.1.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 10.132.2.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.132.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.132.1.10 metric 100 
10.132.2.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.132.2.20 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000
```

Finally, here's the original sshd_config file (note: 10.132.1.10 is a wired network that the computer is on -- ssh has no problem on the wired network):

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port 20
Port 22
#Port 80

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 10.132.2.20:20
ListenAddress 10.132.1.10:22
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: Is there a second network (10.132.1.0/24)? Can you provide your routes (`ip route`)? Also did you disable your firewall, if any, during tests to ensure it's not because of the firewall?

Comment: Two networks:  10.132.1.* which is wired, 10.132.2.* which is wireless.  ip route provided above as edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: Delete the default route to 10.132.1.1 and incoming connections on 10.132.2.x will be successfully returned on the 10.132.2.x network. Note that this relies on the fact that I do not use the 10.132.1.1 for incoming connections.

LONG VERSION:

After posting this question on various forums, someone suggested that my configuration is what is called "dual home", and that I was not set up correctly to support two networks. Some research on this brought me to these entries from "ip route":

```
default via 10.132.1.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 10.132.2.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 600
```

This is saying that the machine is currently set up with two default routes. Putting a tcpdump on the 10.132.1.10 side of COMPUTER B and then attempting to ssh in to 10.132.2.20 showed that COMPUTER B was attempting to send responses with the IP address 10.132.2.20 out on the 10.132.1.x network -- which failed.

The weird thing is that before this, I never detected any problems with this setup. The simple solution for my system was simply to delete the default route on 10.132.1.1. Since the routing tables also include the following:

```
10.132.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.132.1.10 metric 100
```

any connections to local devices continue to work.